# Cannot set title of page loaded through Window.Open

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I am using the code below to show a page from Silverlight

```
public void OpenLinkInNewWindow(string url, int? width = null, int? height = null)
{
    try
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull("url", url);

        if (!width.HasValue)
        {
          width = int.Parse(HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.width").ToString()) - MarginLeft;
        }

      if (!height.HasValue)
      {
        // Subtract the margin twice because of the start menu (which we assume is on the bottom)
        height = int.Parse(HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.height").ToString()) - MarginTop - (MarginTop / 2);
      }

      string sizeJavascript = string.Empty;
      sizeJavascript += string.Format(",width={0}", width.Value);
      sizeJavascript += string.Format(",height={0}", height.Value);

      int leftOffset = MarginLeft / 2;
      int topOffset = MarginTop / 2;

      string javascript = string.Format("window.open('{0}', '', 'left={1},top={2},scrollbars=1,resizable=1,modal=no,alwaysRaised=yes{3}')", url, 
                leftOffset, topOffset, sizeJavascript);

      HtmlPage.Window.Eval(javascript);
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
     //There may be a problem loading the window via Javascript so try to open in new page
     try
     {
       OpenLinkNewPage(url);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        //There is still a problem - perhaps a popup blocker.  So as a last resort, open link in the same page
        OpenLinkSamePage(url);
     }
   }
}

public void OpenLinkSamePage(string url)
{
  HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(url), string.Empty);
}

public void OpenLinkNewPage(string url)
{
   HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(url), "_blank");
}
}
```

This works well in that does load a new window

However, I cannot for the life of me find out how to set the title of this window?

I have tried loads of different ways and none of them work

I have tried PageLoad, using a script tag inside the aspx

I am guessing that this may be a security restriction?

I have seen people suggest putting the result of window.open onto a variable and then settin g the title, but this just results in the page being displayed in a new tab

I do have Report in the markup of my page but this gets ignored

I need this to be displayed in a new window NOT in a new tab

I am using IE 10

Does anyone have any ideas?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, perhaps, this approach:

```
var javascript = string.Format("var win = window.open(); win.document.title('{0}'); win.focus();", "success!");
```

?

Comment: Have just tried this and it doesnt work, I just get an exception "Eval failed"?

Comment: Hi Tim yep I did that. I also tried just selecting the assembly that contains the types and it still doesn't work

Comment: This has now got even stranger!  On my machine this does not work and yet on another machine that also has IE 10, the title is changed correctly and the read only title bar is displayed?